# Issues trying to respond to command-line user input

Tags: java, output

I've created this class along with the linkedlist class and they are in the same folder. The input appears to work fine besides the fact that the runner class won't output anything, even when I enter p  into the command prompt. Even when I encapsulate the methods in System.out.print, nothing happens.

Runner class

```
public class runner{

    static String s;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        linkedlist link= new linkedlist();
        System.out.println("Type a command\n");
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try{
                s=in.readLine();
                char first=s.charAt(0);
                while(in.readLine()!=null){
                    s=in.readLine();
                    int space= s.indexOf(" ");
                        if(first=='i'){
                            String w=s.substring(space);
                            link.insert(w);
                        }
                        if(first=='d'){
                            String w=s.substring(space);
                            link.delete(w);
                        }
                        if(first=='f'){
                            String w=s.substring(space);
                            link.find(w);
                            link.find(w);
                        }
                        if(first== 'p'){
                            link.printlist();
                        }
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Ack!: " + e);
            }finally{
                in.close();
            }
    }

}
```

Linked List class

```
import java.io.*;

public class linkedlist{
node head;
public linkedlist(){
    head=null;
}

public void insert(String s){
    head= new node(s,head);
}

public void printlist(){
    node i= head;
    while(i.getData(i)!=null){
        System.out.print(i.getData(i));
        i=i.getNext();
    }
}

public String find(String s){
    String comp=head.getData(head);
    node ref=head.getNext();
    String check=ref.getData(ref);
    String temp=check;
    while(check != "null"){
        if(s.equals(check)){
            head=ref;
            ref=head.getNext();
            check=ref.getData(ref);
        }
        else{
            temp=check;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public String delete(String s){
    String comp=head.getData(head);
    node ref=head.getNext();
    String check= ref.getData(ref);
    node ref2= ref.getNext();
    String post=ref2.getData(ref2);
    String temp=check;
    while(check != "null"){
        if(s.equals(check)){
            ref=ref2; 
        }
        else{
            comp=check;
            ref=head.getNext();
            check=ref.getData(ref);
            ref2= ref.getNext();
            post=ref2.getData(ref2);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
}
```

Comment: You should also post the code of `linkedlist` especially the insert method.

Comment: @hotzst I added the whole linked list class

Answer (score 1):

I guess it happens because you are swallowing several input lines here:

```
try{
    s=in.readLine();                //you consume one line here         
    char first=s.charAt(0);
    while(in.readLine()!=null){     //you consume another here
        s=in.readLine();            //and another one..
```

replace it with:

```
 while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) { // while loop begins here
     char first=s.charAt(0);
     [...]
 } // end while
```

Comment: It means you have other problems around, but the one solved here _IS_ definitely a problem; proof here: http://ideone.com/z1o8X9

Comment: whoops, please disregard previous link, this is the right one: http://ideone.com/LPA0ms

Comment: Alright thanks. I think i see what you did, but in theory, shouldn't my version work with your modification. Unless my linkedlist isn't actually storing anythign which I don' think is the case

Comment: without seeing the node class, how you call the tree to fill it, it is difficult to say; start with fixing the console input, then move to the rest